# Installing .deb (Brackets.Release.1.13.64-bit.deb) package in arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, deb, pkgbuild, makepkg

The latest release of Brackets (v1.13) is not available in the AUR. So I downloaded the official .deb package from the official site. Now how do I go about installing it ? Do I have to write a PKGBUILD? I won't know it's dependency  and all.
I have converted it to an arch package with Debtap. 
But `pacman -U <Convertedpackage.tar.xz>` throws unresolvable dependency for the following:

```
     warning: cannot resolve "libudev>=147", a dependency of "brackets"
     warning: cannot resolve "lsb-base>=3.2", a dependency of "brackets"
```

How should I go about this ?

Comment: Convert to a `tar.gz` file using `alien`.  Then extract in a directory, check the binaries with `ldd` to make sure you have what they need, and then move files/directories around as needed.  Personally I'd put 'em under `/opt` and manually link binaries, etc to appropriate places under `/usr` or `/usr/local`

Comment: @ivanivan , is it working for you ?

Comment: no, I use Debian and Mint, so ... But this is how I've used packages from other distros successfully in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Brackets 1.13 have some issues on arch linux.
There are two provider for Brackets 1.12 in AUR and both have been flagged old because v1.13 was released more than six months ago.

link- http://blog.brackets.io/2018/06/18/brackets-1-13-is-now-available/

I should have checked the pinned comment by the maintainer.

link - https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/brackets-bin/

Also this.
http://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/14485

So, currently, Brackets 1.13 breaks down in arch Linux and they are waiting for the fix from upstream.